# Algolia + Laravel -- Do not update index at a specific instance of save()

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am using Laravel Scout + Algolia. We have reached our usage limit because every time someone visits a content page on our site I update the entry in the database to increment the page views counter. This then triggers Algolia to update, even though the `page_views` variable isn't even stored in Algolia. I am wondering if there is a way to update the database entry without triggering the Algolia update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation there's a paragraph about that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scout#pausing-indexing).
Basically you can run a closure without syncing to Algolia in this way:

```php
$currentInstance = 'your-model'; // This is the variable you want to inject
App\YourModel::withoutSyncingToSearch(function () use ($currentInstance) {
    // Do the increment, and algolia indexing will not be updated
});
```

Comment: Bless you. I googled this every way I could think of and couldn't find something for it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! If that solved the issue, do not forget to mark the answer as correct!

Comment: I'm still messin with it to see if i can get it to work (; I need to pass a variable into the callback and have never done so with php

Comment: I have updated the answer. Keep in mind that if you pass variables to a callback with `use` they are no longer callbacks, but closure (that's just terminology, nothing fancy but might be helpful to search for the right term)

Comment: You're amazing!